Why does NetworkManager not recognize this example.conf file?
I'm a raspberry pi noob and have been trying to understand why NetworkManager is not accepting this profile whatsoever.
[connection]
id=namelol
UUID=12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-1234567890ab
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
autoconnect-priority=0

[wifi]
ssid=NAMELOL
mode=infrastructure

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto

[proxy]
[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
eap=ttls
identity=your_username
password=your_password
phase2-auth=pap

When I change the wifi-security settings to anything else, it magically gets recognized. For example see below. Even removing the wifi-security thing works. Am I missing some value here? Have I wrongly entered some data?
[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=idklol

ETA: nmcli tool, version 1.42.4, Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
invalid connection: 802-1x: 'wpa-eap' security requires '802-1x' setting presence


Please [edit] your Question and show us the command you used (is there a -v option?), the error messages, and the logs surrounding the failure. Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event. Read man journalctl. Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger.

@waltinator woah, thanks. I have added the error to the question and am trying to find solution which I will also mention if I find.

Does this thread help https://askubuntu.com/questions/839768/how-to-connect-to-a-wpa2-enterprise-with-nmcli-in-a-non-interactive-mode

@XTian Perfect, I got it working! Thanks a lot ^^

I fiddled around with the commands in the link shared by @XTian here and figured that changing [wifi-security] to [802-1x] will get it recognized. To get it working, I had to change the file to this:
[connection]
id=namelol
UUID=12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-1234567890ab
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
autoconnect-priority=0

[wifi]
ssid=NAMELOL
mode=infrastructure

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
auth-alg=open

[802-1x]
eap=ttls
identity=your_username
password=your_password
phase2-auth=pap

[proxy]


Great answer ! If you add your final config it will be perfect.
